# Where can I find Stackdriver in Firebase console?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-stackdriver

I've read in this [article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/announcing-cloud-firestore-general-availability-and-updates) that Firestore has launched Stackdriver (in beta) so we can monitor Cloud Firestore read, write and delete operations in near-real time but where can I find it in Firebase console?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to go to the Google Cloud Console and not to the Firebase console.

The URL is https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?project=xxxxxx

There you will find a set of vertical menu items about Stackdriver. You should use the **Monitoring** menu item to open the Stackdriver console.

[image]

Then once in the Stackdriver console, you should open the **Resources** menu and create a new Metric for your Firestore instance, as shown below:

[image]

---

BTW, Doug Stevenson has recently published a couple of posts which cover (among others) some of the link/differences between the two consoles: https://medium.com/google-developers/firebase-google-cloud-whats-different-with-cloud-functions-612d9e1e89cb and https://medium.com/google-developers/whats-the-relationship-between-firebase-and-google-cloud-57e268a7ff6f