# How to find Google Cloud Platform history logs?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any proper way to get history log data for Google Cloud Platform usage? I'm mainly interested in this (see the screenshot) particular metric (**Cloud Firestore Read Operations**)

[image]

Comment: Stackdriver logs aren't enough?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find Stackdriver in Firebase console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54492115/where-can-i-find-stackdriver-in-firebase-console). This answer shows how to monitor Cloud Firestore Read Operations in Stack Driver.