# Firebase Firestore everyday API call graph?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am not able to find the screen to view everyday detailed graph for API call count for Firebase Firestore. I want to view see graph for read/write count.

I am able to see today's quotas on [this page](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/quotadetails).

I want see `Cloud Firestore Read Operations` & `Cloud Firestore API Calls` for everyday.

Please provide a link for required page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to see the number of reads/writes/deletes in the Firebase Console:

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/your-project-name/database/firestore/usage
```

For other usage statistics, you should use Stackdriver. You will also see the same read/write/delete statistics in Stackdriver, but much detailed. Have a look at this answer: [Where can I find Stackdriver in Firebase console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54492115/where-can-i-find-stackdriver-in-firebase-console/54492936#54492936)

Comment: Thanks Renaud for answer. First link gives information but contains only a small period (ie last week). Where can I see these counts for everyday of last month? Do you have any idea?

Comment: You can see the same reads/write/delete statistics in Stackdriver, much detailed. See the answer I refer to in this answer.

Comment: That is asking amazon login. I did not get that.

Comment: No, you don't need any Amazon login. This is only the case if you want to monitor AWS instances but you are not obliged. See https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/

Comment: Thanks for the useful link. I will go through it.